# Play Video only on Landscape in android API Level 8

Tags: android, view

I want to play the video only in landscape mode. I tried the following code but the entire activity turns on landscape mode but I want only the videoview in the Xml layout to play in the landscape.

```html
<activity android:name=".Video_play"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: You could set it programtically when you start the displaying the video.

Comment: May be you can use this https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout. or you can use `setRotation()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... check the SDK version of the user to match API lvl 8:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
            // This will only hit API lvl 8 
            // myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
```

And `myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

will force you screen to be landscape. Remember to have the xml layout-land to make sure the UI will be good for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file named bools.xml in values folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="bool" name="isPortLayout">true</item>
</resources>
```

create another file in values-land folder named bools.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="bool" name="isPortLayout">false</item>
</resources>
```

Now in your activity before calling to setContentView get this resource and based on its value set Activity as full screen or not:

```
boolean isPortLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLargeLayout);
if(isPortLayout) {
  // PORT
} else {
  // LAND
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Set your VideoView's width and height match_parent.

Comment: OP need to play the video only in landscape mode. Read the question again